# C# Properties and fields

Tags: c#, .net, properties

For the past few years I have been assigning a `C#` Property to a field.

I saw some code today that just had

```
    public String Title
    {
        get;set; 

    }
```

I was thinking this was just un-finished code. However the program worked and returned the Title String!

I have been doing this

```
    private string _title;

    public String Title
    {
        get { return this._title; }
        set { this._title = value; }

    }
```

So here my question is, is there any benefit, or need to write the properties by attaching them to a field like I have been doing for the past 2 years?

Comment: You need to research [auto-implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) properties. (Asking about the benefits is too broad a question for SO.)

Comment: This is fantastic! `public string Address { get; private set; }` - I had no idea (time saver)

Comment: This is called 'auto-implemented' properties, and has been available since C# 3.0. The only possible deficiency I can see of an auto-implemented property is that is cannot be passed as a `ref` parameter.